# Не загружается svg файл в qt 5.6.2

Tags: qt

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не загружается svg файл?

```
QPixmap pix;

auto result = pix.load(":/refresh_.svg");

qDebug()<<result

ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/refresh_.svg"));
```

**result** = false,
**Ошибка:** QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3

https://yadi.sk/d/UKsI8B-HHFTlfg - проект qt

https://yadi.sk/i/QvP2kYJeO4VYZg - файл refresh_.svg

Comment: а почему вы всё еще не обновились? Или вы хотите сразу на Qt 6?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы программа работала под WIndows XP